# How to set the <p:carousel> width dynamically?

Tags: primefaces

I am using Prime faces 3.5 version. Have a page which has panelGrid with 2 columns (width 50% each). Trying to avoid hard coding the size in pixels to occupy the full screen in all screen resolutions. I have p:carousel component in second column of the Grid. For this we have set width:100%. For some reason this is generating 13000 pixels size. Any solution to fix this problem?

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2>
  <p:scrollPanel>
  --some content
  </p:scrollPanel>
  <p:scrollPanel>
   <p:carousel style="width:100%">
  </p:carousel>
  </p:scrollPanel>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**jQuery(".ui-carousel").css("width",'100%');**